# Finding the product of real and imaginary roots separately

Tags: polynomials

If I am given a polynomial of nth degree and asked to fond the product of real and imaginary roots what steps should I take?

I know how to calculate the sum or product of all roots of a polynomial of nth degree but how to separately find the product of real and imaginary roots?

For example  if I'm asked to find the product of real roots of $2x^4 + 3x^3 - 11x^2 - 9x + 15 = 0$.
What steps should I take?

Comment: I think by 2x4 + 3x3 - 11x2 - 9x + 15 = 0 you mean  $2x^4 + 3x^3 - 11x^2 - 9x + 15 = 0$

Comment: Yeah that's it...but, I don't know how to type it that way....

Comment: You ask for different things throughout the question. Title mentions sum and product. Then in the first two paragraphs you ask for the product of real and non-real roots, which can be interpreted as either the product of all the roots or the product of real roots and nonreal roots separately.

Comment: But the question to find the product of all real roots only seems interesting.

Comment: I think now its fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.  Just found a partial  answer for $x^4+a_3x^3+a_2x^2+a_1x+a_0=0$.  Let $y$ and $x$ denote the product of the real and complex roots and $b$ and $a$ the sums of the real and complex roots resp.  Playing Vieta with the coefficients and those sums and product, you will find the following system of equations.

$$\begin{align*}
yx&=a_0\\
a+b&=a_3\\
y+x+ab&=a_2\\
xb+ya&=a_1
\end{align*}
$$

As this system is symmetric in $a\leftrightarrow b$ and in $x\leftrightarrow y$ we expect six solutions.  For the given polynomial Mathematica confronts us with:

$$
\left\{\left\{a\to 0,b\to \frac{3}{2},x\to -3,y\to
   -\frac{5}{2}\right\},\left\{a\to \frac{3}{2},b\to 0,x\to -\frac{5}{2},y\to
   -3\right\},\left\{a\to \frac{1}{2} \left(5-2 \sqrt{3}\right),b\to
   \sqrt{3}-1,x\to -\frac{5 \sqrt{3}}{2},y\to -\sqrt{3}\right\},\left\{a\to
   -1-\sqrt{3},b\to \frac{1}{2} \left(5+2 \sqrt{3}\right),x\to \sqrt{3},y\to
   \frac{5 \sqrt{3}}{2}\right\},\left\{a\to \sqrt{3}-1,b\to \frac{1}{2}
   \left(5-2 \sqrt{3}\right),x\to -\sqrt{3},y\to -\frac{5
   \sqrt{3}}{2}\right\},\left\{a\to \frac{1}{2} \left(5+2 \sqrt{3}\right),b\to
   -1-\sqrt{3},x\to \frac{5 \sqrt{3}}{2},y\to \sqrt{3}\right\}\right\}
$$

Only the first solution fits to the given equation.  At the moment I haven't a clue to de-symmetrize the conditions.  Alas, it's a beginning.

Michael

Answer (score 1):

To find the product of the roots of a polynomial use Vieta's formula which says if $\lbrace r_n \rbrace$ is the set of roots of an $n^{th}$ order polynomial $a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \dots +a_1x + a_0$  , then the product of the roots $r_1r_2 \dots r_n = (-1)^n\frac{a_0}{a_n}$. To find the sum of the roots you use the formula $\sum_{i=0}^{n}r_i = -\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n} $

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. The OP wants to know how to calculate the product (or sum) of the roots that are real (or not real) not the product (or sum) of all the roots.